# Multilanguage Einstein chatbots

Tags: einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

Requirement - My requirement is Multilanguage chatbot based on customer choice the bot should work on customer chosen language.

I tried that one by creating dialogs, entity, variables, in rule actions I have chosen set conversion language. And I added Translated content to my dialogue after activating it is not working based on customer Input. I have attached screenshots for better understanding. Can you please tell me how can I make this work.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create entities with possible values as per salesforce documentation [Set a Bot Conversation Language](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_language_set.htm&type=5) You can provide language code in Entity as per [Supported Languages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm&type=5)